# Is there functionality to change PyQt default colors?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there a way to change the universal default colors of a Qt application?  For example is there a way to set the colors to show up as the dark grey color of the graphs instead of the default light grey. I can go through and set everything individually...but I thought I would check to see if there is an easy way just to set a default instead? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html)  with API `QApplication::setStyleSheet()`